# Express.js - GraphQL API hot reload not work

Tags: node.js, express, server, graphql, hot-reload

I try to write a mockAPI with a hot reload. This means I want to restart/update the server data after I'm editing the schema or the returned data. Everything works like expected. The only thing I'm missing is the reload. Actually, the server is restarting **but the data is still the same** (I was testing it with Postman).

I was assuming that I have to restart the server after I'm editing the schema or the returned data. I noticed that a callback function already exists with **graphqlHTTP** to listen to the schema and the rootValue, but this doesn't work either.

**Note: I don't want to kill the Node process!**

**index.js**

```
/** require file system */
const fs = require('fs');
const md5 = require('md5');
const path = require('path');
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
/** Start MockAPI */
const http = require('http');
const expressModule = require('express');
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql');

module.exports = class mockAPI {
  constructor(options = { host: '127.0.0.1', port: 3000, namespace: '' }) {
    /** start express */
    this.modules();

    this.directories = {
      data: './data',
      schema: './schema'
    };

    this.ignore = ['.DS_Store', 'Thumbs.db'];

    this.host = options.host;
    this.port = options.port;
    this.namespace = options.namespace;

    this.registerRoutes({
      data: this.getRoutes(this.directories.data),
      schema: this.getRoutes(this.directories.schema)
    });

    /** start watching (true) */
    this.start(true);
  }

  modules() {
    /** start express */
    this.express = expressModule();
    this.server = http.createServer(this.express);
  }

  start(watch) {
    /** start server */
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.server
        .listen(this.port, this.host, () => {
          const restart = !watch ? 're' : '';

          console.info(
            '\x1b[1m\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m\x1b[0m',
            `\n> MockAPI server ${restart}open on ... http://${this.server.address().address}:${
              this.server.address().port
            }\n`
          );
          /** start watching API files */
          if (watch) this.watch(this.directories);
        })
        .on('error', err => {
          if (err) reject(err);
        });

      resolve();
    });
  }

  stop(restart) {
    /** stop server */
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.server.close(err => {
        if (err) reject(err);

        const color = restart ? '33' : '31';
        const message = restart ? 'restart' : 'closed';

        console.info(
          `\x1b[1m\x1b[${color}m%s\x1b[0m\x1b[0m`,
          `> MockAPI server ${message} on ... http://${this.host}:${this.port}`
        );

        resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  watch(directories) {
    this.md5Previous = null;
    this.fsWait = false;

    Object.keys(directories).map(key => {
      const dir = directories[key];

      fs.watch(path.resolve(__dirname, dir), { recursive: true }, (event, filename) => {
        if (event === 'change' && filename) {
          /** if people exec multiple times save */
          if (this.fsWait) return false;

          const md5Current = md5(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, `${dir}/${filename}`)));
          /** compare file hashes */
          if (md5Current === this.md5Previous) return false;

          /** restart server */
          this.fsWait = true;
          setTimeout(async () => {
            this.fsWait = false;
            this.md5Previous = md5Current;

            console.info('\x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m', `- ${filename} changed`);
            /**
             * any solution here?
             * in this scope
             */
            await this.server.removeAllListeners('upgrade');
            await this.server.removeAllListeners('request');

            await this.stop(true);

            await this.modules();
            await this.registerRoutes({
              data: this.getRoutes(this.directories.data),
              schema: this.getRoutes(this.directories.schema)
            });

            this.start(false);
            /**
             * any solution here?
             * in this scope
             */
          }, 1000);
        }
      });
    });

    return true;
  }

  getRoutes(dir) {
    const absPath = path.resolve(__dirname, dir);
    let routes = [];

    const readDir = path => {
      let data = [];

      fs.readdirSync(path, { withFileTypes: true }).forEach(file => {
        if (this.ignore.includes(file.name)) return false;

        if (file.isDirectory()) return readDir(`${path}/${file.name}`);

        const route = path === absPath ? '' : path.replace(absPath, '');
        const name = file.name.replace(/\.js|\.graphql/, '');
        const endpoint = name.replace(/\s+/g, '-');

        data.push({
          name: name,
          dir: route,
          file: file.name,
          route: `${route}/${endpoint}`
        });
      });

      routes = [...routes, ...data];
    };
    readDir(absPath);
    /** sort array by route */
    return routes.sort((a, b) => a.route.localeCompare(b.route));
  }

  registerRoutes(routes) {
    if (routes.schema.length !== routes.data.length) {
      console.error(
        '\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m',
        `- schema.length(${routes.schema.length}) !== data.length(${routes.data.length}).\n  Each schema must match a data file in the same file structure with the same file name.`
      );
      process.exit;
    }

    routes.data.forEach(async (vdata, key) => {
      if (vdata.route === routes.schema[key].route) {
        const typeDefs = await readFileSync(
          `./mock-api/schema${routes.schema[key].dir}/${routes.schema[key].file}`
        ).toString('utf-8');

        let schema = await buildSchema(typeDefs);
        let data = await require(`./data${vdata.dir}/${vdata.file}`);

        this.express.use(
          this.namespace + vdata.route,
          graphqlHTTP({
            schema: schema,
            rootValue: data,
            graphiql: true
          })
        );
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Would be great if someone can help me out.

If you want to reproduce the process, just create a directory **/data** and **/schema** in the same root directory as this code/snippet/file and call any **yarn** or **npm** command, to load this module (index.js). Inside of the **/data** directory place a JS file to describe the resolvers and a GraphQL file in the **/schema** directory to describe the schema. Each file must have the same name to match the route, which is registered by the file structure.

So if you place **/data/test/data.js** in /data you have to write the schema in **/schema/test/data.graphql** and it is accessible with **http://127.0.0.1/test/data**.

Here are examples to quickly reproduce.

**data.js**

```
/**
 * Returns GraphQL data
 * @returns {object} data
 */
module.exports = {
  hello: () => {
    return 'Hello world!';
  }
};
```

**data.graphql**

```
type Query {
  hello: String
}
```

To clarify what I want is, I need to flush, clear, delete, or any other method to delete the stored data.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a child process with spawn.

**index.js**

```
/** file system */
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
/** require environment variables */
let env = require('../config/env');
/**
 * Returns Mock API server as child process
 * @param {boolean} initial process
 * @returns {object} process data
 * --------------------------------
 */
const server = initial => {
  /** merge environment variables */
  env = Object.assign(process.env, env, { INITIAL: initial });

  /** start child process for the Mock API */
  let child = spawn('node', ['mock-api/MockAPI.js'], {
    env: env
  });

  /** child info/logs */
  child.stdout.on('data', data => {
    try {
      /** check if data is object */
      const obj = JSON.parse(data.toString());
      /** handle object data */
      if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, 'restart')) {
        child.kill();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(data.toString());
    }
  });

  /** child errors */
  child.stderr.on('data', data => {
    console.error(
      '\x1b[1m\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m\x1b[0m',
      `> Mock API server crashed on ... http://${env.MOCK_API_HOST}:${env.MOCK_API_PORT}\n`,
      data.toString()
    );
  });

  child.on('close', () => {
    /** Wait for process to exit, then run again */
    setTimeout(() => server(false), 500);
  });

  /** kill child process if parent process gets killed */
  process.on('exit', () => child.kill('SIGINT'));

  return child;
};

module.exports = (() => server(true))();
```

**MockAPI.js**

```
/** file system */
const fs = require('fs');
const md5 = require('md5');
const path = require('path');
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
/** server data */
const http = require('http');
const expressModule = require('express');
const express = expressModule();
const server = http.createServer(express);
/** graphql */
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql');
/** define globals */
const data = './data';
const ignore = ['.DS_Store', 'Thumbs.db'];
const env = process.env;
const host = env.MOCK_API_HOST || '127.0.0.1';
const port = env.MOCK_API_PORT || 3000;
const namespace = env.MOCK_API_NAMESPACE || '';
/**
 * get routes data from ./data directory
 *
 * NOTE:
 * each graphql schema must
 * match a JS data file in
 * the same directory
 *
 * @param {string} directory
 * @returns {Array} routes
 */
const getRoutes = dir => {
  const root = path.resolve(__dirname, dir);
  const routes = [];

  const data = path =>
    fs.readdirSync(path, { withFileTypes: true }).forEach(file => {
      if (ignore.includes(file.name) || file.name.endsWith('.graphql')) return false;

      if (file.isDirectory()) return data(`${path}/${file.name}`);

      const name = file.name.replace(/\.js/, '');
      const route = path === root ? '' : path.replace(root, '');
      const endpoint = name.replace(/\s+/g, '-');

      routes.push({
        name: name,
        data: file.name,
        directory: route,
        graphql: `${name}.graphql`,
        route: `${route}/${endpoint}`
      });
    });
  data(root);

  return routes;
};
/**
 * register all routes
 *
 * NOTE:
 * each graphql schema must
 * match a JS data file in
 * the same directory
 *
 * @param {Array} routes
 */
const registerRoutes = routes => {
  routes.forEach(async route => {
    const graphql = path.resolve(__dirname, `./data${route.directory}/${route.graphql}`);
    await fs.stat(graphql, (error, stats) => {
      error, stats;
    });

    const data = path.resolve(__dirname, `./data${route.directory}/${route.data}`);
    await fs.stat(data, (error, stats) => {
      error, stats;
    });

    const typeDefs = await buildSchema(readFileSync(graphql).toString('utf-8'));
    const rootValue = await require(data);

    express.use(
      namespace + route.route,
      graphqlHTTP({
        schema: typeDefs,
        rootValue: rootValue,
        graphiql: true
      })
    );
  });
};
/**
 * start watching data files
 *
 * stop current process if files
 * were edited and restart the server
 *
 * @param {String} directory
 */
const watch = directory => {
  let md5Previous = null;
  let fsWait = false;

  fs.watch(path.resolve(__dirname, directory), { recursive: true }, (event, filename) => {
    if ((event === 'change' || event === 'rename') && filename) {
      /** if people exec multiple times save */
      if (fsWait) return false;

      const md5Current = md5(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, `${directory}/${filename}`)));
      /** compare file hashes */
      if (md5Current === md5Previous) return false;

      /** restart server */
      fsWait = true;
      setTimeout(async () => {
        fsWait = false;
        md5Previous = md5Current;

        console.info(
          '\x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m',
          `- ${filename} changed\n> Mock API server restarts on ... http://${host}:${port}`
        );

        /** restart child process */
        console.log(JSON.stringify({ restart: true }));
      }, 2000);
    }
  });
};
/**
 * initialize server
 */
const init = () => {
  registerRoutes(getRoutes(data));

  server
    .listen(port, host, () => {
      const open = env.INITIAL === 'true' ? 'open' : 'reopened';

      console.info(
        '\x1b[1m\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m\x1b[0m',
        `> Mock API server ${open} on ... http://${server.address().address}:${
          server.address().port
        }`
      );

      /** start watching data files */
      watch(data);
    })
    .on('error', error => {
      if (error) console.log('[ERROR] Mock API: ', error);
    });
};

init();
```